# elemMatch for fields in different levels

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I'm asking this question after trying solve this problem all day long.
I want to get my users address by `userId` and by `addressId`. Since I receive data from post requests, I need to ensure that the query contains both `userId` and `addressId` in order to avoid security problems. The result of the query below returns all addresses from my user, instead of just the address containing the correct `addressId`.

```
async getUserAddress(_id: string, addressId: string) {
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne(
            {
                _id,
                addresses: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        addressId: Types.ObjectId(addressId)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        if (!user) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return user.addresses[0];
    }
```

Since is impossible to use `$elemMatch` in different document levels, or even at the top level of the query, I find no better way to make this query without using filters. Are there any insights?

Tks in advance

Comment: It would be better if you can give sample docs & required o/p rather than giving us code, in general all questions tagged to mongo will better be understood that way !! Please edit your question..

Comment: `findOne` will return an entire document as stored in the database.  If you want to filter out some of the array elements, you will need to either use `aggregate` or filter the array on the client side.